# Can i have multiple sprites in 1 prefab spawner?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I have made a little game where prefab spawners drop obstacles down, and you have to dodge them, now I think it's a little bit boring to have 1 sprite drop continuously.

How can I manage to change the sprite every time it drops an obstacle?

Comment: Maybe add the unity 3d tag to this

Comment: but it is unity2d

Comment: I see @whatsthepoint fixed it up.

Comment: What does you current code look like? Just so the answer can be based on what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Sprite array in the spawner script:

```
[Header("The sprites to drop.")]
public List<Sprite> sprites;
```

Then you can roll a random number and set the SpriteRenderer to the the index of that random number. Something like:

```
void OnSpawn(){
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.count)];
}
```

That should set a new sprite randomly and add some variety.